# How many can speak English given the following conditions?

Tags: percentages

> In a class of 60 students,40% speak only Hindi(H).25% speak only English(E) and the rest can speak both the languages.How many speak English.

**MyApproach**

Using VennDiagram,I see $40$% only H and $25$% only E.

Now,$40$% of $60$=$24$ This means $24$ students opted for Hindi out of $60$

and  $25$% of 60 students choose English means $15$ students opted for English out of $60$.

15 is the Ans.

But the Ans given is 36.

> Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The students how speak English are exactly the students who are not part of the 40% that speak only Hindi. That is, 60% speak English, which is 36. You've counted the students who speak only English.

Comment: The rest is 35% who speak both languages. Add 25% who speak only English and you get a total of 60% who speak (at least) English. Now 60% of 60 is $\color{blue}{36}$ which is the required answer.

Comment: Great:I can solve this problem in now 3 ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have counted the students who only speak english(15), however, you might have students who speak english as well as hindi, which here is 21. So the total becomes 36.